Is it correct to use px within sizes img attribute
I read articles about sizes attribute, the problem is
such articles uses vw units for sizes attribute.
The question is, can px unit be used for sizes attribute,
f.e like this:
<img src="https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/products-taxonomy-images-4/armor/main-image-default.webp"
     srcset="https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/products-taxonomy-images-4/armor/main-image-default.webp 433w
         https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/products-taxonomy-images-4/armor/main-image-575.webp 545w,
         https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/products-taxonomy-images-4/armor/main-image-767.webp 510w,
         https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/products-taxonomy-images-4/armor/main-image-991.webp 690w,
         https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/products-taxonomy-images-4/armor/main-image-1199.webp 363w"
     sizes="(max-width: 575px) 545px,
     (max-width: 767px) 510px,
     (max-width: 991px) 690px,
     (max-width: 1199px) 363px"
     class="c-catalog-3__image" alt="Image">


Yes, according to HTMLImageElement sizes attribute documentation. You can use relative units (em), absolute units (px), vw etc., you can't use percentage values only.
